# Group of order 100

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that in any group of order 100 , either every element has order that is a power of a prime or there is an element of order 10. 
Without using Sylow's theorem how to approach this problem ? 
By Lagrange's theorem , possible orders of elements of G are 1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50 and 100. 
Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What if there's an element of order $20$?

Comment: Thanks i got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You're on the right track. The list contains only $10, 20, 50, 100$ which are not prime powers. If e.g. $x$ has order $50$, then $x^5$ has order $10$.

Comment: Thanks . I got it.

Comment: If |x|= 20, x^ 2= 1

Comment: Likewise it can be solved.